# Issuing commands from console through PHP

Tags: php, command-line, imagemagick, tesseract

I am experimenting with code that will use some algorithm, in which it will order a command line tool to give certain output.

here is my code :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES['file_up']["name"])){

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$file_name")){

   $onlyname = pathinfo($_FILES['file_up']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

//execute command to convert pdf to tif through LOCALLY INSTALLED image rick
    $last_line = system("/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-1/bin/convert -density 300 -trim $onlyname.pdf  -quality 100 ocr_binary.tif", $retval);

    if ($retval == 0){

    echo "First command executed !";    
    $last_line = system("/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/3.05.01/bin/tesseract ocr_binary.tiff $onlyname -l mar", $retval);
    if ($retval == 0){
    echo "success";
        }
     }
else{
        echo "ERROR in command one";
    } }
    else {
      echo "<P>MOVE UPLOADED FILE FAILED!</P>";
   }
exit();
}
?>
```

In this code, I am commanding ImageMagick and tesseract through a PHP (given 777 permissions to) script and folder.

Problems :

- ImageMagick not converting to TIF
- Return error code is 1 (I gave 777 permission to folder and script)

Please help

Comment: I am guessing you either have not installed `ghostscript` or you do not have the correct path which includes `ghostscript` set up for your PHP `system()` call.

Comment: Ghost script is installed

Comment: can u tell orshow me another answer which can help me

Comment: In Terminal, try `which gs`, then in PHP, `system("which gs");`

Comment: Did you work it out?

Comment: no, it didn't but I found something. If I run just Imagick -version, it works and my second command is working.